# How can I exclude an object from receiving shadows?

Tags: unity

I would like to make it so that a certain object is being excluded from receiving shadows.

While it itself should cast shadows onto other objects, it should not receive shadows from other objects.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using HDRP.

Seemingly, the option not to receive shadows is not present when using HDRP.

The MeshRenderer looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Presumably you tried [setting the Receive Shadows property on the object's renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-receiveShadows.html)? Where did you run into trouble with it?

Comment: @DMGregory This property can only be accessed via code, can't it?

Comment: No, it is exposed in the Inspector [as you can see in this image from the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/class-MeshRenderer-0.png)

Comment: @DMGregory For HDRP, this option doesn't seem to exist, I have added a screenshot to my post. I have tried to set it via a script, but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity bug support told me that this can be achieved by using HDRP Light Layers and pointed me to this for a start:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/light-layers-in-hdrp.619609/